# Reshaping Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm parsing some HTML data using Pandas like this:

```
rankings = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankings_of_universities_in_the_United_Kingdom')
university_guide = rankings[0]
```

This gives me a nice data frame:
[image]

What I want is to reshape this data frame so that there are only two columns (rank and university name).  My current solution is to do something like this:

```
ug_copy = rankings[0][1:]
npa1 = ug_copy.as_matrix( columns=[0,1] )
npa2 = ug_copy.as_matrix( columns=[2,3] )
npa3 = ug_copy.as_matrix( columns=[4,5] )

npam = np.append(npa1,npa2)
npam = np.append(npam,npa3)

reshaped = npam.reshape((npam.size/2,2))

pd.DataFrame(data=reshaped)
```

This gives me what I want, but it doesn't seem like it could possibly be the best solution.  I can't seem to find a good way to complete this all using a data frame.  I've tried using stack/unstack and pivoting the data frame (as some of the other solutions here have suggested), but I haven't had any luck.  I've tried doing something like this:

```
ug_copy.columns=['Rank','University','Rank','University','Rank','University']
ug_copy = ug_copy[1:]
ug_copy.groupby(['Rank', 'University'])
```

There has to be something small I'm missing!

Comment: OK, I see your problem you have data spanning across multiple columns, you need to concat the various columns into a single df, I'd first fix the column names and it will be easy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a bit shorter (also note that you can use the `header` option in `read_html` to save a bit of work):

```
import pandas as pd
rankings = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankings_of_universities_in_the_United_Kingdom', header=0)
university_guide = rankings[0]
df = pd.DataFrame(university_guide.values.reshape((30, 2)), columns=['Rank', 'University'])
df = df.sort('Rank').reset_index(drop=True)
print df
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had overlooked the `.values` command...very helpful!